# build.xml not running junit testcases

Tags: java, xml, build, junit4

InsertionTest.java

```
package efms.db.dao.impl;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collection;
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.junit.runners.Parameterized;
import org.junit.runners.Parameterized.Parameters;

@RunWith(value = Parameterized.class)
public class InsertionTest {

    int num1;
    int num2;
    int num3;

    public InsertionTest(int num1, int num2, int num3) {
        super();
        this.num1 = num1;
        this.num2 = num2;
        this.num3 = num3;
    }

    @Parameters
    public static Collection<Object[]> data() {
        Object[][] data = new Object[][] { { 1, 1, 2 }, { 2, 2, 4 } };
        return Arrays.asList(data);
    }

    @Test
    public void testSummationPositive() {
        Assert.assertEquals("Sum should be 4", num1 + num2, num3);
    }

}
```

build.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project basedir="." default="all" name="Junit TestCase Execution">
    <property name="p" location="" />
    <property name="prj" value="" />
    <path id="tests.classpath">
        <pathelement location="${p}/${prj}/build/classes" />
        <pathelement location="${p}/lib/junit.jar" />
        <pathelement location="${p}/lib/hamcrest-core-1.3.jar" />
        <pathelement location="${p}/lib/../*.jar" />

    </path>
    <target name="compile">

        <echo message="${p}/${prj}/build/classes" />
        <javac srcdir="${p}" destdir="${p}/${prj}/build/classes" classpathref="tests.classpath">
            <classpath>
                <pathelement location="${p}/lib/**/*.jar" />
            </classpath>
            <include name="**/InsertionTest.java" />
        </javac>
    </target>



    <target name="junit" depends="compile">
        <echo message="${p}/${prj}/build/classes/" />

        <junit fork="yes" printsummary="yes">

            <formatter type="xml" />
            <!-- Add all your test class names here. -->
            <formatter type="plain" />
            <batchtest todir="${p}/${prj}/build/classes">
                <fileset dir="${p}/${prj}/build/classes/">
                    <include name="**/InsertionTest.*" />
                </fileset>
            </batchtest>

            <classpath>
                <pathelement location="${p}/lib/junit.jar" />
                <pathelement location="${p}/lib/hamcrest-core-1.3.jar" />
            </classpath>
        </junit>
    </target>

    <target name="report" depends="junit">
        <junitreport todir="${p}/${prj}/build/classes">
            <fileset dir="${p}/${prj}/build/classes">
                <include name="TEST-*.xml" />
            </fileset>
            <report format="frames" todir="${p}/${prj}/build/classes" />
        </junitreport>
        <record name="${p}/${prj}/build/classes/test-output.txt" action="start" />
    </target>

    <target name="all" depends="compile,junit,report">

    </target>
</project>
```

Error :

```
efms.db.dao.impl.InsertionTest

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: efms.db.dao.impl.InsertionTest
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
```

I have written a simple junit testcase , when I am running build.xml , file is compiling but while running the junit testcases it is showing error . I guess there is some issue with build.xml . Can I get help in fixing that ?

While compiling :

```
          [javac] Compiling 1 source file to C:\Users\IBM_ADMIN\workspace1\Efms3.3\build\classes
junit:
     [echo] C:\Users\IBM_ADMIN\workspace1\Efms3.3//build/classes/
    [junit] Running efms.db.dao.impl.InsertionTest
    [junit] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0 sec
    [junit] Test efms.db.dao.impl.InsertionTest FAILED
report:
[junitreport] Processing C:\Users\IBM_ADMIN\workspace1\Efms3.3\build\classes\TESTS-TestSuites.xml to C:\Users\IBM_AD~1\AppData\Local\Temp\null2013296782
[junitreport] Loading stylesheet jar:file:/C:/Rahul/RahulDrive/Software/Development%20Tools/Apache/apache-ant-1.9.2-bin/apache-ant-1.9.2/lib/ant-junit.jar!/org/apache/tools/ant/taskdefs/optional/junit/xsl/junit-frames.xsl
[junitreport] Transform time: 491ms
[junitreport] Deleting: C:\Users\IBM_AD~1\AppData\Local\Temp\null2013296782
all:
BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 3 seconds
```

Comment: I have pasted error above in my quetion , while running ant build I am getting

Answer (score 1):

Your Ant code says the classpath to be used for running tests is:

```
<classpath>
    <pathelement location="${p}/lib/junit.jar" />
    <pathelement location="${p}/lib/hamcrest-core-1.3.jar" />
</classpath>
```

You need to add a few more things to the classpath:

1. The unit tests themselves
2. The code you are trying to test (when it is not in the same place)
3. Any jars needed by the above

Note that you can refer to a path defined elsewhere rather than duplicate everything:

```
<path refid="tests.classpath"/>
```

For more information, see the [path documentation](http://ant.apache.org/manual/using.html#path)

Comment: The dead giveaway is that the test class itself isn't found.